# Comparing lists in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I need to compare two lists of values to determine whether they are the same or not in excel. Each value is in a different horizontal cell as shown in my illustration. How can I build a formula to do this task.

```
1 2 3 4 5           should say No
1 2 3 5 4

4 5 1 2 3           should say Yes
4 5 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(A1:D1<>A2:D2))=0, "Yes", "No")
```

SUMPRODUCT is a special function that works on an array basis, it ends up comparing each set of cells to each other, e.g. A1<>A2, B1<>B2, etc.

Comment: Nice! I've needed to do this many times and have always relied on a ugly set of vlookup and iif formulas. This is much better, thanks @Lance.

Comment: How would you approach this problem if it weren't values but text?

Comment: @Flethuseo, it also works for text as written.